# Problems passing PHP string to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

Im having problems passing PHP Strings to Javascript functions, I'v read a number of the post regarding this problem and tried several methods but none of them have worked for me.
basically I have two functions one written in PHP that pulls information from a database and the other written in Javascript designed to allow me to geocode an address for google maps and pass some info to be added to the info window, the two bits of code are shown below:

PHP

```
try {
        $bubbleData = $dbConnection->getBubbleData();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "The following error occoured while attempting to get Google map info window data" .
        " " . $e->getMessage() .
        " " . "In file" .
        " " . $e->getLine() .
        " " . "on line" .
        " " . $e->getLine();
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($bubbleData) == 0) {
        echo "No Placement data found to populate map";
    } else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($bubbleData)) {
            $companyName = $row['Company_Name'];
            $title = $row['Title'];
            $address_1 = $row['Address_Line_1'];
            $address_2 = $row['Address_Line_2'];
            $address_3 = $row['Address_Line_3'];
            $address_4 = $row['Address_Line_4'];
            $post_Code = $row['Post_Code'];
            $forename = $row['Forename'];
            $surname = $row['Surname'];

            $fullAddress = $address_1 . " " . $address_2 . " " . $address_3 . " " . $address_4 . " " . $post_Code;

            $partAddress_1 = $address_1 . " " . $address_2;
            $partAddress_2 = $address_3 . " " . $address_4;

            $infoText = "<h4>" . $title . "</h4>" .
                    '<b>' . "Company name:" . '</b>' . " " . $companyName .
                    "</br>" .
                    "<b>" . "Employee name:" . '</b>' . " " . $forename . " " . $surname . '</br>' .
                    "<b>" . "Company address:" . "</b>" . " " . $partAddress_1 . '</br>' .
                    $partAddress_2 . '</br>' . $post_Code;

    echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
    geocodeAddress(<?php echo json_encode($fullAddress);?>,<?php echo json_encode($infoText);?>);
    </SCRIPT>'";
        }
    }
```

Javascript

```
function geocodeAddress (address,infoText) {

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    loadMarker(results[0].geometry.location,infoText,address);
                    latlngArray.push(results[0].geometry.location);
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +" "+  status);
                }
            });
        }re
```

Now I know that the two work fine individually but whenever I try to call the javascript in side the PHP and pass it the variables I ge the following error in firebug:

> Invalid value for property address:

I've been trying to make this happen all day, Ive used regexs plane echos and the json_encode() function and nothings worked can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will give you a hint: `echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
    geocodeAddress(<?php echo json_encode($fullAddress);?>,<?php echo json_encode($infoText);?>);
    </SCRIPT>'";` is wrong. Check manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have nested `<?php ?>` inside PHP code, which will not be interpreted as PHP. Rather, it just prints into your output as a string.

```
 // Instead of
 echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
    geocodeAddress(<?php echo json_encode($fullAddress);?>,<?php echo json_encode($infoText);?>);
    </SCRIPT>'";

 // Change to
 echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
    geocodeAddress(" . json_encode($fullAddress) . "," . json_encode($infoText) . ");
    </SCRIPT>'";
```

Comment: If you echo out the result from json_encode, into javascript, without echo'ing out quotes, wouldn't it just be interpreted as an object literal in js? meaning the first bit of code would probably work and the second would need quotes to make the output a string and not have JSON.parse throw an error.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That is correct, thanks, and I have edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, I have noticed that

```
<?php ...foo... ?>
```

segments in the HTML body, get php-evaluated only if the file extension is .php.
That is, I had to rename:

```
mv foo.html foo.php
```

to have php-values passed into javascript variables.